# krb5 extension, 2 Duplicate symbols, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: php, makefile, duplicates, installation, symbols

I am trying to install a PHP extension for kerebos auths (https://pecl.php.net/package/krb5), on my OSX, i have downloaded the extension and now i am trying to install it but i am getting an error about 2 duplications. I have also installed autoconfig to run ./configure, i didnt have it already installed by default.

I was trying to follow the install guide file:

```
+ When compiling this extension as shared module:
  - run phpize in the extension directory
  - run ./configure (optionally add --with-krb5kadm if you need this functionality)
  - run make && make install
  - optional: enable your new extension in you php.ini
```

And when i try to make && make install i receive this error:

```
duplicate symbol _krb5_ce_ccache in:
    .libs/krb5.o
    .libs/negotiate_auth.o
duplicate symbol _krb5_ce_ccache in:
    .libs/krb5.o
    .libs/gssapi.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [krb5.la] Error 1
```

I notice that both files (krb5.o and gssapi.o) seems to be encripted from nano command line view =/ so i made a check in krb5.c, negotiate_auth.c  and gssapi.c (Both links for this files are here to see http://pastebin.com/zNdGzLFj)

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it in Download folder and i was unable to to it at the time (dont know why), then i did it in Documents, and it solves.

That first command doesnt command in the install file, it was given by the extension author:

```
# This will put the current development source into the folder php_krb5
svn co https://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/krb5/trunk/ php_krb5
# Go there
cd php_krb5
# Build and install
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

Also the argument --with-krb5kadm is responsible for flags enables bindings for MIT kerberos' administration API (that
allows you to manage principals, policies and so forth).

To activate this plugin i had to search for krb5.so, copy that location and then search for php.ini and then add this line to that file:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/krb5.so
```

The location that you see is for my system, yours could be different.

To test if you have choose right your krb5.so (i had 3) you could confirm it by doing:

```
php -m
```

In this list you will see that krb5, if you add well the krb5.so.

**Thank you very much Moritz Bechler!!!**